# libtorrent + python basic Functions

Tags: python, libtorrent

I am building a python app using libtorrent, But its hard to find good documentation for it.

How to :

- Get the total size or an easy way to calculate it?
- Get the number of files

I found a bug that

```
s = h.status()
s.progress*100
```

Never return 100 on completion, instead it return some thing like 99.87954613....

Comment: Which libtorrent are you using?

Answer (score 1):

TO check whether you've completed you can call to h.is_seed() method which will return true if you are only seeding.

So something like

```
while not h.is_seed():
   //Keep on downloading

print "all done"
```

Comment: yes, but the progress will not retrun 100% when h.is_seed() is true.

Comment: @limovala and? SO is not a bug-tracking site but a place where you can come and get some answers, some solutions and a workaround for said bug was presented.